# How to test more than one var if is empty in PHP?

Tags: php

How can i test a var if its empty or not?
i have this array

```
array($myname,$myhouse,$mywife);
```

How can I check each of them if it empty or not **without using a loop**?

Comment: Probably best to state in the question that you don't want to use a loop, before everyone's answer gets downvoted because they didn't know your intentions.

Comment: I'm curious: why without a loop? And What is the content of the variables? A string? An Array again?

Comment: @ Robert Greiner  Ok will voteup everyone now

Comment: Why would you not want to use a loop? Any solution that doesn't xplicitly require you to write a loop will use a loop internally.

Comment: As you can read in other comments a loop is done in any case, implicitly or explicitly. A sequence (array) is a continuous area in your memory. To access single values, you have to access this memory area at certain positions. And as the word sequence already implies, this can only be done sequentially. You cannot process every single value at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're asking for is either impossible or facetious. You either need to explicitly test each variable by name or use a loop to test a dynamic collection of variables.

Comment: There are some ways… wondering why this answer has already 5 upvotes.

Comment: And now even accepted? Weird. There are already some clever answers.

Comment: Even the clever answers have loops, but they're hidden from the developer. Perhaps this was an assignment/homework question?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner is correct -- every method you could propose to do this requires a loop or an explicit listing. Array_map loops over all the items in an array. Concatenating values together can't be done without iterating over the contents of the array.

Just because you didn't write 'foreach' doesn't mean it's not a loop.

Comment: Yeah it's silly. Not *writing* a loop doesn't mean you aren't using one. The only other option is checking the values one by one hardcoding them

Answer (score 7):

One line (except the function of course):

```
function not_empty($val) {
    return !empty($val);
}

$result = array_product(array_map('not_empty',$array));
```

The result is `0` if one variable is empty otherwise `1`.
**But of course it won't tell which one is empty. ;)**

See [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [array_product](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php).

Comment: Oooh this is clever! ...but of course, using mapping functions implies that there is still some looping going on behind the scenes.

Comment: this is really really clever! Nice one.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean without writing a loop then you can use:

```
in_array(true, array_map(create_function('$x', 'return empty($x);'),$array));
```

Implicitly it will of course loop through your array, twice in fact! Once to check the emptiness, then again to check the result. You're better of with a loop you can break when you hit a non_empty value.

Comment: Oh that's also a good one! Still has lot of implicit loops though.

Answer (score 3):

```
$myvars = array($myname, $myhouse, $mywife);
foreach ($myvars as $value) {
  if (empty($value)) {
    // value is empty
  }
}
```

**edit**: Here is a version which does not use a loop:

```
$myvars = array($myname, $myhouse, $mywife);
$myvars_filtered = array_filter($myvars, "empty"); // or isset, if you prefer
if (count($myvars_filtered) > 0) {
  // one or more values were empty
}
```

Note that, as Felix commented, when you use `"isset"` instead of `"empty"`, you will get all values that have a value, instead of the ones that don't. So in that case you need to compare the amount of elements in `$myvars` to the count of elements in `$myvars_filtered`.

Comment: @streetparade: check each one separately? `if (empty($myname) || empty($myhouse) || empty($mywife))
{...}`

Comment: but that also to long version

Comment: @streetparade: If you don't want to spell out each variable and you don't want a loop, you will have to use magic. Try `require "magic.php";`

Comment: Be careful with interchanging `empty` and `isset`. When using `isset` you get all variables that are set and with `empty` all that are **not** set/empty. Apart from that, nice solution *THUMBS UP* :)

Answer (score 2):

Try [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Edit-
Use the code posted above, but change the function:

```
$myvars = array($myname, $myhouse, $mywife);
foreach ($myvars as $value) {
 if (isset($value)) {
  // Not set
 }
}
```

[According to this, isset is marginally faster.](http://www.blueshoes.org/phpBench.php)

Comment: Yeah but howto check eachone if is isset?

Comment: You need to loop through them.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that doesnt use a loop:

```
<?php
$my_house = "";
$my_name = "Foo Bar";
$my_wife = "Angelina";

$arr = array($my_house, $my_name, $my_wife);
preg_replace("/.+/","-",$arr,-1,$count);
if ($count == 3) {
  # everything is filled
} else {
  # missing somehwere
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are ways to do it. One of them:

```
<?php
$array = array('myname' => 'Jakob', 'myhouse' => '', 'mywife' => 1);

$empty_elements = array("");
$array = array_keys(array_intersect($array,$empty_elements));

var_dump($array);
?>
```

outputs:

array
  0 => string 'myhouse'

Some other possibilities for a similiar problem (removing the empty ones): http://hasin.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/removing-empty-elements-from-an-array-the-php-way/

Comment: In the link you can see why he presumably doesn't want a php-loop: It's way slower than using internal loops.